# Cant retrieve all contacts from yahoo

Tags: api, contacts, yahoo

I followed [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yap/guide/other-code-exs.html#my_social) tutorial to retrieve contacts from yahoo. It works ok but the problem is that it doesnt not retrieve contacts that I have imported into yahoo, just the ones that I added manually. Does anyone know if you can import the imported contacts to somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Print it, copy paste into excel, filter with "contains @" and put emails into one column and same with "doesn't contain @" and another column. Then in Data tab do Text to columns and split first name/last name into two columns. Paste this now into proper format for import into gmail.

Key is that imported contacts still show up in print.